How do I extract information from stim.PauliString?
Suppose I have stim.PauliString("+Z_Z_ZZ__"). I want to extract its data information in Python: either as a string "+Z_Z_ZZ__" or some binary vector.
How should I do this?

Note: copied over from https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/745

You can use stim.PauliString.to_numpy to extract the XZ-encoded Pauli information from a pauli string as numpy arrays, and stim.PauliString.sign to get the sign.
For large Pauli strings, you can use stim.PauliString.to_numpy(bit_packed=True) to get an output that's 8x smaller. For sparse Pauli strings, you can use stim.PauliString.pauli_indices to get a result that skips over identity terms.
import stim
p = stim.PauliString("+Z_Z_ZZ__XYZ")
xs, zs = p.to_numpy()
print("xs", xs)
print("zs", zs)
print("sign", p.sign)
# Prints:
# xs [False False False False False False False False  True  True False]
# zs [ True False  True False  True  True False False False  True  True]
# sign (1+0j)

packed_xs, packed_zs = p.to_numpy(bit_packed=True)
print("packed_xs", packed_xs)
print("packed_zs", packed_zs)
print("bin(packed_xs)", ' '.join(bin(e)[2:].rjust(8, '0')[::-1] for e in packed_xs))
print("bin(packed_zs)", ' '.join(bin(e)[2:].rjust(8, '0')[::-1] for e in packed_zs))
# Prints:
# packed_xs [0 3]
# packed_zs [53  6]
# bin(packed_xs) 00000000 11000000
# bin(packed_zs) 10101100 01100000

print("xyz_indices", p.pauli_indices())
print("x_indices", p.pauli_indices('X'))
print("y_indices", p.pauli_indices('Y'))
print("xz_indices", p.pauli_indices('XZ'))
# Prints:
# xyz_indices [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]
# x_indices [8]
# y_indices [9]
# xz_indices [0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10]

